# How do I get information on linux whether my program is swapping or not?

Tags: linux, posix, bsd

More specifically: I want to find this information from inside the program, preferably just before it starts swapping so I can react. So far I found:

- Information inside `/proc`, which is not very useful
- `mincore` syscall which seems to be available on linux and bsd, but requires me to pass in all the pages I'm interested in (might be enough, but it's a bit tedious)

Any more ideas?

Comment: In addition to monitoring (which you can then setup for alarms) you could also take a look at /proc/sys/vm/swappiness, but this depends on your app and what other uses your machine has. Maybe you can also  disable swap entirely (if your app can handle OOM situations).

Comment: That doesn't make sense. I'm talking about PyPy (which is a python interpreter) that can trade memory for speed. It's unlikely to have privileges of setting swapiness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vmstat

To run every 2 seconds, you say "vmstat 2". It gives you output like:

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0  16124 431352 439000    0    0     4     2   37   18  0  0 100  0  0
```

The "si" and "so" columns are "swap-in" and "swap-out". Swapd is how much memory is in the swap device. Swapd should be stable, and si and so zero.

**Remember:**

You shouldn't really ask "is my program swapping" - as opposed to "is the *system* swapping". You program can cause others to swap - others can cause yours to swap, etc. Either way, when that happens - performance d...i..e...s....

Comment: Right, this is what I meant :-)